# Field or property "StorageMetrics" does not exist." Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, dynamics-365

I have an issue with SharePoint 2013 (Version 15) and Dynamics 365 OnPrem. I have integrated the two systems to enable document management. All seemed to work fine, the scenario is that an Email in CRM gets converted to a case and then the attached documents gets uploaded to a folder in SharePoint with that case number as the folder name.

All is well, up until I enable versioning on the SharePoint side. Immediately after that my code doesn't work, and I get the following error **Field or property "StorageMetrics" does not exist." Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException**

See my code below.

```
 public static void UploadFile(IOrganizationService service, EntityReference sharepointSiteId, EntityReference parentSiteOrLocationId, string fileName, byte[] fileStream, Dictionary<string, object> properties = null, bool overwrite = false)
    {
      string sharepointSiteUrl = SharepointDocumentLocationManager.RetrieveAbsoluteAndSiteCollectionUrl(service, sharepointSiteId).AbsoluteUrl;
      using (ClientContext sharePointContext = SharepointManager.GetClientContext(sharepointSiteUrl))
      {
        string parentSiteOrLocationUrl = SharepointDocumentLocationManager.RetrieveAbsoluteAndSiteCollectionUrl(service, parentSiteOrLocationId).AbsoluteUrl;
        if (overwrite || !SharepointManager.FileExists(sharePointContext, parentSiteOrLocationUrl, fileName))
        {
          SharepointManager.UploadFile(sharePointContext, parentSiteOrLocationUrl, fileName, fileStream, properties);
        }
      }
    }


public static bool FileExists(ClientContext context, string absoluteBaseUrl, string fileName)
    {
      Folder folder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(absoluteBaseUrl);
      context.Load(folder.Files);

      context.ExecuteQuery();

      return folder.Files.Any(file => file.Name.ToLowerInvariant() == fileName.ToLowerInvariant());
    }
```

The error happens on this line. context.ExecuteQuery();

Does anybody have an idea of what is causing this, I am mostly a Dynamics 365 developer, not too clued up on the SharePoint side. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should have sp SP version > 15